# How to extract less.js parser results as object instead compiled CSS with .toCSS()?

Tags: less

i would like to know if there is a way to get the less parse results as object instead as compiled CSS?
In the usage example we have:

```
var parser = new(less.Parser);

parser.parse('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (err, tree) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err) }
    console.log(tree.toCSS());
});
```

which is fine but I need to do some work withe the "raw" rules set in JavaScript. How one gets access to the rules set as an object. For instance:

```
var rules_set = {
selector:'xxxxxxx'
property1: 'xcv'
.
.
.
propertyX: ''
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tree` object actually *is* the object containing the parse results, it contains arrays/objects representing all parsed LESS entities, e.g. `tree.rules` etc. (You may look for what you need via some javascript debugger (browser's built-in one for example)).

Of course these "parsed entities" are represented in LESS's own internal format (usually it's a dedicated object for each language unit/structure i.e. `tree.Value`, `tree.Rule`, `tree.Mixin`, `tree.Variable` etc. etc.).

As for the documentation of all above, obviously there's no such thing as "LESS Compiler Internals Reference Guide", the only documentation of the LESS internals is the source code itself.

Comment: Right i see that the tree.rules contains what i am looking for when I browse it (with dev tools) BUT the point is that the tree structure changes and want to build my extractor function consistent! That is why i ask for internals and the structure details to do it. If you have such info it will help!

Comment: @LiliputFX Tree structure is not changed after you get it in the `function (err, tree)` callback. I.e. you can modify all those things before the `tree.toCSS()` call (Or write your own `toWhatever`function using original `toCSS` as reference).

Comment: :)Sure it does not change after i got it in the callback...I had in mind that tree structure is content dependant. Parsing different less will result in different tree structure. I look for a way to use the parser results! I want to store them in DB but not as a useless string...

Comment: "I want to store them in DB but not as a useless string..." - So you'll have to write your own function that converts the parsed tree structure to "not-so-useless" string. LESS does not have any function to convert parsed tree to anything beside CSS because it simply does not need such facility on its own. Though I wonder what can be a purpose of storing an *intermediate* parser results in a DB... (can't you just store the input LESS string itself? it's still strange but at least not so complicated).

Comment: Thank You! Accepting the answer...The purpose is to also use less as "pure" CSS parser because it is loaded already and skip implementing my own(or use/load available external solution). The app cares about the final CSS so it needs it in an object form stored in the db to be reachable on property level not sheet level as a string. Again thanks!

Comment: @LiliputFX, Thanks, yes, I was just about to add a comment like "LESS is actually is not really a LESS parsing library, it's just a simple compiler with essentially the only functionality - 'convert/compile LESS code to CSS code' - no more than just that. So something like "LESS to JSON" or a sort of would not be so easy to achieve using existing sources". Probably I could guess of that "compiler vs. parsing library" confusion a bit earlier, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The example above failed with a "cannot read property 'cntents' of undefined" error.  Here is code that seems to work with LESS 2.5.0:

```
var parser = new(less.Parser)({}, {contents: {}}, {
    relativeUrls: true,
    rootpath: "/",
    filename: 'main.less'
});
parser.parse('x {y: url("../z.png")}', function (e, tree) {
   console.log(tree);
});
```